# Maths in processing language

Tags: programming-languages, processing

Ok, so I am a little lost with Processing Programming Language again, so wondering if anyone can help my brain become unblocked?

This is the question - "Write a program which compares two numbers, if one of the numbers is    larger  than the other then the two numbers are added together and the  result is printed in the console window."

So I have got this, but im getting errors on just the 'int' value code which is making me think ive completely misunderstood this?.. possibly misunderstood how the language works :/

Here is my code;

```
void setup() {
int a = 30
int b = 20

 if (a > b) {printIn("a+b");}
 }
```

Comment: is this code snippet C language? post the definition of `printIn()` function. maybe you need to use `printIn(a+b)` without the quotes. use semicolons to end sentences too.

Comment: @logoff It's in Processing, which is kind of a dialect of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it helps if you post *what* errors you're getting. However, in this case you have a very basic syntax problem: you need to terminate your statements with semicolons - including the assignments. Eg: `int a = 30;`

Oh, and it's `println` (with a lowercase L) not `printIn`. And, as noted by logoff, you're doing the sum inside a quoted string, which will just print as a literal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understad it correctly you have to declare the variables outside the setup() method. Intialization can be done inside the method.

Comment: Not true. Note, however, that variables inside the method are **local** and will not persist beyond the method call. In this case that is unlikely to matter.

Answer (score 0):

The l in println(); should be lowercase.
There is no need for the quotes around the variables.

This works:

void setup() { int a = 30; int b = 20; if(a > b) {println(a + b); }}